# What's the exact value of $y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, exponential-function

Given that $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x-y}$ and $y=1$ when $x=0$ find the exact value of $y$ when $x=1$.

After my attempts. I stuck in $$y=e^{1-y}+1-e^{-1}$$ How to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A start: Rewrite as $e^y\frac{dy}{dx}=e^x$. This is a separable equation. Integrate. We get $e^y=e^x+C$. Continue.

Comment: y=1.48988. Is it correct ?

Comment: We have $y=1$ when $x=0$. So $C=e-1$. When $x=1$, we have $e^y=2e-1$, so $y=\ln(2e-1)$.  This is the **exact value** asked for.  You did the problem correctly, but what you gave is an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempted solution is incorrect.  Hint: the differential equation $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^{x-y}$ is separable.